# Populating Jquery datepicker with date returned from asp.net web api

Tags: jquery, asp.net, date, asp.net-web-api, datepicker

I am having problems with something that should be trivial. I have a web api that returns dates in the following format:

`2014-01-06T09:46:12.7819007+01:00`

If I am not mistaking, this is a very common iso format. When I feed it to the `jQuery` `datepicker` it interprets this date as 7323-10-27. The problem seems to be the time segment of the date.

This: `2014-01-06T09:46:12.7819007+01:00`
Gets parsed as: `7323-10-27`

This: `2014-01-06T09:45:35`
Gets parsed as: `2019-10-03`

This: `2014-01-06T09:45:35`
Gets parsed as: `2019-08-29`

This: `2014-01-06`
Gets parsed, not surprisingly, as: `2014-01-06`

So how do I tell the `datepicker` to ignore the time part of the date? I tried fiddling with the dateFormat option to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting that string to an actual Date and give that to the datepicker:

```
var defaultDate = new Date('2014-01-06T09:46:12.7819007+01:00');
```

When supplying the date as a string it need to match the `dateFormat` parameter, but creating a format for that in JS will be a headache that's best avoided.